# How to navigate language specific characters with latin character in html select form?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, character-encoding

I need to navigate an HTML select dropdown with a latin letter and it should match "similar" characters. For example latin letter A should also match language specific Ă and Â.

Given options Audi, Ăudi and Âudi in a dropdown, pressing A will only match Audi but I want it to also match Ăudi and Âudi.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GAWFUUJ3BBP8